# Class, pointer, vector and delete

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, vector

Suppose I have:

```
class A {
public:
    A(HWND hwnd, HWND hwnd2);
    ~A();

    int  i;
    HWND hwndFrame;
    HWND hwndCanvas;
    bool bool;

};

class B {
public:
    B(HWND hwnd);
    ~B();

    HWND hwndFrame;
    Vec<A *> vecA;  // class Vec is implemented by someone else.

};
```

Suppose I have created:

```
A * elementA1 = new A(...);
A * elementA2 = new A(...);
B * element B = new B(...);
B->vecA.Append(A1);
B->vecA.Append(A2);
```

At some point, I would like to delete all the above objects (so they don't exist in the memory anymore).

I am very confused how to do it.

My questions are:

1. If I put `delete hwndFrame` in the destructor `~A();`, then when I do `delete A`, do `hwndFrame` is really deleted?
2. In the destructor `~B()`, what I have to do in order to `delete` (from memory) the vector `B->vecA` and the contents that its elements point to, i.e the contents that `A1` and `A2` point to.

Comment: `hwndFrame` is not a pointer type; you cannot invoke `delete` on it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I put delete hwndFrame in the destructor ~A();, then when I do delete A, do hwndFrame is really deleted?

You shouldn't be trying to delete a `HWND`, its an opaque pointer handle. You may instead call on it functions like `DestroyWindow` or similar, depending on what you really want to do.

> In the destructor ~B(), what I have to do in order to delete (from memory) the vector B->vecA and the contents that its elements point to, i.e the contents that A1 and A2 point to.

You have to iterate over each element of each vector, and call `delete` for each of them.